# Why beta process is useful ?

Tags: nonparametric, stochastic-processes

Why Beta process is useful/important? How different is that from Dirichlet process?

Comment: could you please be more specific what it is that you want to know and in what context? The way the question is currently framed is pretty broad.

Comment: I noticed that several of your questions often lack context or would lead to very open-ended discussion. I encourage you to re-read our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) ("ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"), and, in the case you want to solicit expert opinion on broad topics, to focus on a particular issue or to narrow down the question.

Comment: I am looking for a very general understanding of their differences; that's why I haven't pointed out any specific detail. Could you give a high-level intuition?